# Call method from parent to child via component

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a Two components

1)Job.jsx -parent
2)Jobmodel.jsx -child

So I have a method in job.jsx

```
const [joblist, SetJoblist] = useState([]);
    const loadJobs = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/getJobs");
        const data = await res.json();
        const list = data.job;
        SetJoblist(list);
    
    
      }
```

so I want to call the same from child after modal close function.so I tried

```
 <Jobdetailsmodal location={location} method={loadJobs}/>
```

and child function like

```
export default function Jobdetailsmodal({location},{loadJobs}) {
 function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
loadJobs();
}
}
```

but I got the error

> TypeError: loadJobs is not a function

Any help would be highly appreciate

Comment: Typo? The prop name is `method` and you should destruct the props like `function Jobdetailsmodal({location, method}) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing some syntax issues here.
You should destructure your props like this (since the props that you give to your component are stored in an single object):

```
export default function Jobdetailsmodal({location,method}) { ... }
```

Note that I named the function that you are passing as `method`, since it is the name you gave to it here:

```
 <Jobdetailsmodal location={location} method={loadJobs}/>
```

You could totally name it `loadJobs`, but then you have to be consistent, so you use the same name when you pass the prop to the component, and in the component.